# Rsyslog - How do you use stop in the control structure without affecting other rules?

Tags: filtering, rsyslog, control-structure

How can I apply many control flows without interfering with each other?

For example, many network devices will send messages to that port. I want to create rulesets that will drop logs according to different parameters.

```
input(type="imudp" port="514")

ruleset(name="drop_cisco") {
   if ($msg contains "cisco") then {
      stop
   }
}
ruleset(name="drop_juniper") {
   if ($msg contains "juniper") then {
      stop
   }
}

ruleset(name="drop_hp") {
   if ($msg contains "hp") then {
      stop
   }
}

ruleset(name="drop_SilverPeak") {
   if ($msg contains "SilverPeak") then {
      stop
   }
}

ruleset(name="action1") {
   action(type="omfile" file="/app/rsyslog/output/devices1.log")
}

ruleset(name="action2") {
   action(type="omfile" file="/app/rsyslog/output/devices2.log")
}

ruleset(name="action3") {
   action(type="omfile" file="/app/rsyslog/output/devices3.log")
}

ruleset(name="action3") {
   action(type="omfile" file="/app/rsyslog/output/devices3.log")
}

ruleset(name="rule1") {
   call drop_cisco
   call action1
}

ruleset(name="rule2") {
   call drop_cisco
   drop_SilverPeak
   call action2
}

ruleset(name="rule3") {
   call drop_juniper
   call drop_SilverPeak
   call drop_hp
   call action3
}

ruleset(name="rule4") {
   call drop_hp
   call drop_juniper
   call action4
}


call rule1
call rule2
call rule3
call rule4
```

Each time I call a rule, the filter will apply to the call below. Can I bind port 514 to each rule individually? Like so:

```
input(type="imudp" port="514" ruleset="rule1")
input(type="imudp" port="514" ruleset="rule2")
input(type="imudp" port="514" ruleset="rule3")
input(type="imudp" port="514" ruleset="rule4")
```

Is there a better way to do that?

Thank you,